# JSON no me reconoce un objeto interno

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy creando un menú de manera dinámica por medio de  una función, esta función debe recibir como parámetro un JSON quien contendrá toda la estructura y jerarquías del menú, el problema que al momento de concatenar me dice que un elemento interno del JSON no lo reconoce.

Les voy a dejar el código, espero que alguien me pueda ayudar

```js
function CrearMenu(caja, objeto) {

  var esqueleto = '<nav clase="nav"><ul clase="Menu">';

  var Primer_Nivel = Object.keys(objeto).length;

  for (var i = 0; i <= Primer_Nivel; i++) {
    esqueleto = esqueleto + '<li><a href="' + objeto[i].href + '">' + objeto[i].titulo + '</a></li>'

    //alert(objeto[i]);
  }

  esqueleto = esqueleto + '</ul></nav>';
  $(caja).append(esqueleto);
}
$(document).ready(function() {

  var obj = [{
      "titulo": "Fernando",
      "href": "#",
      "submenu": [{
          "titulo": "Vannesa",
          "href": "#",
          "submenu": []
        },
        {
          "titulo": "Martha",
          "href": "#",
          "submenu": []
        },
        {
          "titulo": "Guiocasta",
          "href": "#",
          "submenu": [{
              "titulo": "Karen",
              "href": "#",
              "submenu": []
            },
            {
              "titulo": "Jessica",
              "href": "#",
              "submenu": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "titulo": "Jennifer",
      "href": "#",
      "submenu": []
    },
    {
      "titulo": "Lucia",
      "href": "#",
      "submenu": []
    }

  ];
  CrearMenu("#caja", obj);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="caja">
</div>
```

El problema es que cuando lo ejecuto dice que href no esta definido y si lo quito me dice lo mismo pero con titulo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema es que estás recorriendo los objetos del array hasta que `i` sea **menor o igual** a `Primer_Nivel`.

Tienes que recordar que los arrays empiezan desde la posición 0 por lo que tendrás que recorrer el bucle desde 0 hasta 2, es decir, cuando `i` sea **menor** que `Primer_Nivel`.

El error que te está dando es que estás intentando acceder a la posición 3 del array `objeto`, la cual no existe, ya que solamente contiene las posiciones 0, 1 y 2.

Tu ejemplo corregido:

```js
function CrearMenu(caja, objeto) {

  var esqueleto = '<nav clase="nav"><ul clase="Menu">';

  var Primer_Nivel = Object.keys(objeto).length;

  for (var i = 0; i < Primer_Nivel; i++) {
    esqueleto = esqueleto + '<li><a href="' + objeto[i].href + '">' + objeto[i].titulo + '</a></li>'

    //alert(objeto[i]);
  }

  esqueleto = esqueleto + '</ul></nav>';
  $(caja).append(esqueleto);
}
$(document).ready(function() {

  var obj = [{
      "titulo": "Fernando",
      "href": "#",
      "submenu": [{
          "titulo": "Vannesa",
          "href": "#",
          "submenu": []
        },
        {
          "titulo": "Martha",
          "href": "#",
          "submenu": []
        },
        {
          "titulo": "Guiocasta",
          "href": "#",
          "submenu": [{
              "titulo": "Karen",
              "href": "#",
              "submenu": []
            },
            {
              "titulo": "Jessica",
              "href": "#",
              "submenu": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "titulo": "Jennifer",
      "href": "#",
      "submenu": []
    },
    {
      "titulo": "Lucia",
      "href": "#",
      "submenu": []
    }

  ];
  CrearMenu("#caja", obj);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="caja">
</div>
```